# Batch script that separates that creates folder by month

Tags: encoding, batch-file, directory

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion

REM Set variables
SET SOURCE=C:\My WebEx Recordings
SET DEST=\\XXXRD12\c$\WebExVideoArchive
SET 7ZIP=C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe

REM Compress local files with 7zip
ECHO ---------------------------------------------------------
ECHO    BEGINNING VIDEO COMPRESSION OPERATIONS
ECHO ---------------------------------------------------------
CD /D "%SOURCE%"
FOR %%f in ("*.wrf") DO (
    SET FILENAME=%%~nf
    ECHO Compressing !FILENAME!
    "!7ZIP!" a -t7z -aoa "!FILENAME!.7z" "%%f"
)

REM Copy compressed files
ECHO ---------------------------------------------------------
ECHO    COMPRESSION COMPLETE - BEGINNING COPY OPERATIONS
ECHO ---------------------------------------------------------
REM XCOPY <source> <destination> <options>
XCOPY "%SOURCE%\*.7z" "%DEST%" /Y /V /I /R

REM Confirm successful copy, then delete originals
IF %ERRORLEVEL% EQU 0 (
    ECHO Copy Operation Successful. Removing Originals...
    DEL /Q "%SOURCE%\*.*"
)ELSE (
    ECHO Error Detected During Copying. Please try again...Press Any Key to Exit    
    Pause
)
```

I am trying to edit this code to when we run the batch file it creates a folder based off the month of our file format. We ran this script a whole lot but forgot to make a folder called April now we have May mixed in with April.

The files are formatted like

```
Username-R705-2011.05.04-1601-Disconnected.7z
```

I was wondering if there is anyway it can go off the .04 and make a folder for that month so it will automatically put it in the folder it is needing to go into, so it will be easy to search for by month.

** would it be possible if we can not use the format that we format our files in to have it sort by file creation.

Comment: Why don't you use powershell? its much more powerfull and has lots more you can do with it. :)

Comment: yea i am not sure i didnt write it. I was given this task to fix it to make it do what it needs to do. I am more of a php coder but i will check out powershell. I am also on a xp box

Comment: What is the date format?  Is it YYYY.MM.DD or YYYY.DD.MM?

Comment: Also, does the folder name have to be "APRIL" or is "04" okay?  "APRIL" will make the batch file longer.

Comment: 04 is fine. april doesnt have to be on there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Erase everything below (and including) the line `REM XCOPY <source> <destination> <options>` and replace it with the following:

```
for /F "usebackq delims=" %%a in (`dir /b "%SOURCE%\*.7z"`) do (
    SET CURRENT_FILE=%%a

    REM Extract the month.
    for /F "usebackq tokens=3 delims=-" %%i in ('!CURRENT_FILE!') do (
        SET CURRENT_FILE_DATE=%%i
        SET FILE_MONTH=!CURRENT_FILE_DATE:~-2!
        SET MONTH_DEST=!DEST!\!FILE_MONTH!
    )

    XCOPY "%SOURCE%\!CURRENT_FILE!" "!MONTH_DEST!\" /Y /V /I /R

    REM Confirm successful copy, then delete original
    IF %ERRORLEVEL% EQU 0 (
        ECHO Copy Operation Successful. Removing Original...
        DEL /Q "%SOURCE%\!CURRENT_FILE!"
    )ELSE (
        ECHO Error while copying "%SOURCE%\!CURRENT_FILE!.
    )
)
```

This code goes through every file matching `%SOURCE%\*.7z`, extracts the month, and then copies the file to `%DEST%\<month>`.  Month is just the 2-digit number from the filename.

Comment: indiv your code is awesome and it does work but i tried a few tests with it and if i have a file like USERNAME-RCODE-2011.05.02-1314-Disconnected_2.7z for whatever reason it made a folder called 2 and there was one that was 03 so its reading the 2011.05."02 or 03" thats the date. how do i set it to the "05" or "0x" middle number. but your code is right on

Comment: @Alex:  Change the line `SET FILE_MONTH=!CURRENT_FILE_DATE:~-2!` to `SET FILE_MONTH=!CURRENT_FILE_DATE:~5,2!` to extract the middle 2 digits instead of the last 2.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you have a folder full of files with different numeric-month values embedded in the filename.  I was thinking of extracting that value from each file, but it would be more straightforward to use brute force wildcards with 12 different XCOPY commands:

```
XCOPY "%SOURCE%\*-*-20??.??.01-*.7z" "%DEST%\01" /Y /V /I /R
XCOPY "%SOURCE%\*-*-20??.??.02-*.7z" "%DEST%\02" /Y /V /I /R
[...]
XCOPY "%SOURCE%\*-*-20??.??.12-*.7z" "%DEST%\12" /Y /V /I /R
```

I may be misunderstanding the question but if you can make some assumptions about the filenames, this would work.

Comment: Vik what I am trying to do is we record remote sessions for our company and when we save our files at the end of the day they save to Username-R705-2011.05.04-1601-Disconnected.7z
but when we do that they are put into the place on the server like it shows in the script. so what i need is when we save the file it needs to be put in that month folder like 01, 02, 03 so no one has to go in and mess with files. that way at the end of the month I can login and burn them all to a dvd. I hope that helps.

Comment: Okay that sheds some light on the specifics and the good news is the filename follows a specific syntax. The solution about may still work because each command would only pick out the files for that particular month.  So January files will get moved to %DEST%\01 and so on.

Comment: awesome thanks so much so i just add your code to
XCOPY "%SOURCE%\*.7z" "%DEST%" /Y /V /I /R

right